# Force placement of sidewaysfigure

Tags: floats, positioning, rotating

I have several large figures which need their own page. I would like to force the figures to occupy adjacent pages, starting from where I place the code for the first figure.

Regular figure environments take the option [H] from the float package, but this seems to not work with sidewaysfigure. Is there a workaround, or do I just have to settle with my figures being all over the place?

Comment: Try a `\clearpage` command just before each of the commands to load the figures you want on adjacent pages.  Not elegant, but should work.

Comment: package pdflscape, try this.

Comment: If they occupy an entire page you should use [p] (page) not [H] (here).